# Federation Server Error 1054: Unknown column 'domain' in 'where clause'

Tags: federation, memo

In an every user has their own Stellar account setup, I am trying to get federation server to work but keep failing. The mysql tables are

1. CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
   `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `friendly_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `public_key` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   `domain` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;``

**The federation.cfg file query is setup with:**
federation = "SELECT public_key as id FROM accounts WHERE friendly_id = ? AND domain = 'mdxfederation.space'"

**My get request**
curl "https://mdxfederation.space:8002/federation?q=tunde_adebayo*mdxfederation.space&type=name"

**it throws the same error**
ERRO[5796] lookup record: db get: get failed: Error 1054: Unknown column 'domain' in 'where clause'  pid=2271

ps. There is no memo_type field in my .cfg file

Answer (score 1):

Just need to remember any changes to either the db or the cfg will require a restart of the federation server. I also turned off query caching in the db.